# How to get the device volume values to my app

Tags: iphone, stack, volume

I am using volume in my app using MPMusicPlayerController with plus and minus buttons for increasing and decreasing the volume(for increasing and decreasing indicates through horizontal images). While pressing the buttons(user defined) volume works good, if i use the device volume button volume is adjusting but its not syncing with app volumes button, i.e the images for increasing and decreasing are not getting called.

Simply, how can get the device volume values to my app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651252/how-to-get-audio-volume-level-and-volume-changed-notifications-on-ios-4) thread. It also has some example code. Look at Sandy's answer!