# Changing Device Volume

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipod

I am developing an Iphone/Ipod Application, in which I am using AVAudioPlayer. I am changing volume of audio through slider, which works correctly, but now I have to change(increase/decrease) slider by pressing the device plus and minus button instead of changing slider by myself. When I press plus/minus button of device, don't know where the control goes? Does anybody know, feel free to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slam and thanks all! I have searched on it. This is valid for MPMusicPlayer, but not for AVAudioPlayer.
You can do it.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *_musicController = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

But not this for AVAudioPlayer,

```
AVAudioPlayer *_audioController = [AVAudioPlayer iPodMusicPlayer];
```

Answer (score 2):

> **How do I access the hardware volume controller?**
>
> *Global system volume, including your application's volume, is handled by iPhone OS and is not accessible by applications.*

Here is link kindly read it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html)
Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Please download this.     http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't entirely clear to me, but it seems you're wanting a notification when the system volume changes? If so, this is possible, I hope I understand your question correctly. How about the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
     name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
     object:nil];
}

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    float volume =
    [[[notification userInfo]
      objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
     floatValue];

    // Do stuff with volume
}
```

I grabbed this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651252/how-to-get-audio-volume-level-and-volume-changed-notifications-on-ios-4), Sandy's answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i have already visited it. I just want to know that where I can receive response after pressing plus/minus button on device.

Comment: hello @paul , would u pls tell me .. here the volume is changing through buttons what it is said to be as?. Ringer volume of device volume of audioplayer volume?