# iPhone:How to detect an Iphone/Ipod volume level using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, avaudioplayer

I am developing app using AVAudioPlayer and I want to detect the volume level of my devices
i.e. iPhone/iPad then How can I do it?

Actually I want to detect when the iPhone/iPad is in silent mode then what is its volume level?

Any Idea? share it.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
     name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
     object:nil];
}

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    float volume =
    [[[notification userInfo]
      objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
     floatValue];

    // Do stuff with volume
}
```

Please see the answer details on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651252/how-to-get-audio-volume-level-and-volume-changed-notifications-on-ios-4) thread.

Comment: The volumeChanged method was never called when I implemented this in my ApplicationDelegate, despite adjusting the volume.